# Connecting IOS app to Raspberry Pi 4 over bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I created a new app with swiftUI and trying to use coreBluetooth library to connect Raspberry Pi 4. I searched all the google and I stuck at connecting Raspberry Pi 4. I can find all the devices (peripherals) but I'm not able to connect them.

Here is the code;

```
class BLEManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    
    var myCentral: CBCentralManager!
    
    @Published var isSwitchedOn = false
    @Published var peripherals = [Peripheral]()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()

        myCentral = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        myCentral.delegate = self
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            isSwitchedOn = true
        }
        else {
            isSwitchedOn = false
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        var peripheralName: String!
       
        if let name = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
            peripheralName = name
        }
        else {
            peripheralName = "Unknown"
        }
       
        if peripheral.identifier.uuidString == "6D915395-3E79-0072-22A3-009DDC331F7C" {
            myCentral.stopScan()
            myCentral.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            print("okokokokok")
        }
        
        let newPeripheral = Peripheral(id: peripherals.count, name: peripheralName, rssi: RSSI.intValue)
        print(newPeripheral)
        peripherals.append(newPeripheral)
    }
    
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!,didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!)
    {
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        print("Connected")
        print(peripheral.name!)
        print(peripheral.services!)
    }
    
}
```

Deleted some of code parts bc of stackoverfow

Comment: So you see *okokokokok* printed but don't see *Connected* right?

Comment: You should've implemented the [didFailToConnect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518988-centralmanager) and also [didDisconnectPeripheral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518791-centralmanager) in order to see any possible connection failure. Implement it; put a print statment where you print the error if any.

Comment: @Kozmotronik Yes. That's true

Comment: By the way, the error that im getting with this file says that im not holding the peripheral and not connecting

Comment: That's it! *im not holding the peripheral* this is the problem

Comment: Actually now it connected. I used "didConnect" to check connection  and now it says connected. Thanks for helping! BTW do you know how can I send data to Raspberry ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem for the connection was not holding a reference to the CBPeripheral object to which you want to connect. So you've solved it by referencing to it in your `BLEManager` class.

Now how can you send and get data to / from your Raspberry? Well you must implement the [`CBPeripheralDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate) in your `BLEManager` class.

1. After the central manager finishes discovering the available services it will call [didDiscoverServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518744-peripheral) method of `CBPeripheralDelegate`; where you need to invoke [discoverCharacteristics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518797-discovercharacteristics) for the discovered service.
2. Again, when characteristics has been discovered for the given service with the `discoverCharacteristics(_:for:)` method which you invoked in the `didDiscoverServices` callback, you can set the notify value if you want to know about characteristic updates.
3. After the characteristics has been discovered you can send values by using [writeValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1519107-writevalue) method of [CBPeripheral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral) instance to which you've referenced it when connected.
4. When you send data from the Raspberry for a certain charachteristic, the [didUpdateValueFor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral) method of `CBPeripheralDelegate` will get called. In this callback; you can obtain the received data from the [CBCharacteristic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristic).[value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristic/1518878-value) property. Note that the `value` property is optional, hence you need to handle it with care.